# Is there any way to implement Alphabetical section index in recyclerview using cursoradapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, simplecursoradapter

I need to implement alphabetical sectionindexer in my recyclerview.  I have found many libraries but non of it make use of Cursoradapter how to implement sectionindexer for recyclerview using cursoradapter here let me post my adapter class can someone tell me way to start this here is my adapter class:

```
  import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.TextDrawable;
    import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.util.ColorGenerator;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import model.CustomerModel;
    import timertracker.precision.timetracker.R;

    public class CustomerListAdapter extends CursorRecycleViewAdapter<CustomerListAdapter.MyViewHolder>  implements View.OnClickListener {
        private List<CustomerModel> dataSet;
        String companygrp;
        int position;
        ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
        private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

        public CustomerListAdapter(Context mContext, Cursor cursor) {
            super(mContext, cursor);
        }


        public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
            this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
        }



        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            // Model_Task_List Model_Task_List=new Model_Task_List();
            TextView textname;
            TextView textaddress;
            TextView textphnum;
            TextView textdegree;
            TextView textemail;
            ImageView call;

            public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                this.textname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
                this.textaddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.customerstatus);
                this.textphnum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
                this.textdegree=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
                this.call = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.customeradapterview, parent, false);

            MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            return myViewHolder;
        }

        public void addModelClass(CustomerModel modelClass) {
            dataSet = new ArrayList<CustomerModel>();
            dataSet.add(modelClass);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, Cursor cursor) {
            TextView textViewName = holder.textname;
            TextView textViewaddress = holder.textaddress;
            TextView textid = holder.textphnum;
            TextView textemail=holder.textdegree;
            companygrp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_Name));
            String email=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_EmailID));
            if(email.length()>=20){
                String s=  email.substring(0,20)+"...";
                textemail.setText(s);
            }
            else {
                textemail.setText(email);
            }
            //textemail.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_EmailID)));
            String status=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_Status));
            if(status.equals("Active")){
                textViewaddress.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#006400"));
            }
            else {
                textViewaddress.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8B0000"));
            }
            textViewaddress.setText(status);
            textid.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_MobileNumber)));
            String s1 = companygrp.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + companygrp.substring(1).toLowerCase();
            textViewName.setText(s1);
            ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.DEFAULT;
            String com= s1.substring(0,1);
            TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                    .buildRound((com).toUpperCase(), generator.getRandomColor());
            holder.call.setImageDrawable(drawable);

         /*  for (int i = 0; i < companygrp.length(); i++) {
                String s1 = companygrp.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + companygrp.substring(1).toLowerCase();
                textViewName.setText(s1);
                ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.DEFAULT;
                String com= s1.substring(0,1);
                TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                        .buildRound((com).toUpperCase(), generator.getRandomColor());
                holder.call.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            }*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.getParent();
            position = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(v);
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                final Cursor cursor = this.getItem(position);
                this.onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(cursor);
            }

        }

        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onItemClicked(Cursor cursor);
        }

    }
```

How to implement the section header for this thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, you can do

#### Here is a adapter uses AlphabetIndexer

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter  implements SectionIndexer{

AlphabetIndexer mAlphabetIndexer;

public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int simpleListItem1,
        Cursor cursor, String[] strings, int[] is)
{
    super(context, cursor);

    mAlphabetIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(cursor,
            cursor.getColumnIndex("person"),
            " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTSUVWXYZ");
    mAlphabetIndexer.setCursor(cursor);//Sets a new cursor as the data set and resets the cache of indices.

}

/**
 * Performs a binary search or cache lookup to find the first row that matches a given section's starting letter.
 */
@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex)
{
    return mAlphabetIndexer.getPositionForSection(sectionIndex);
}

/**
 * Returns the section index for a given position in the list by querying the item and comparing it with all items
 * in the section array.
 */
@Override
public int getSectionForPosition(int position)
{
    return mAlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(position);
}

/**
 * Returns the section array constructed from the alphabet provided in the constructor.
 */
@Override
public Object[] getSections()
{
    return mAlphabetIndexer.getSections();
}

/**
 * Bind an existing view to the data pointed to by cursor
 */
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
{
    TextView txtView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    txtView.setText(cursor.getString(
            cursor.getColumnIndex("person")));
}

/**
 * Makes a new view to hold the data pointed to by cursor.
 */
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View newView = inflater.inflate(
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
    return newView;
}
}
```

Here is a complete example http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/02/10/Implementing-a-ListView-with-AlphabetIndexer-and-CursorAdapter-on-Android

You can also refer

1. http://hello-android.blogspot.com/2010/11/sideindex-for-android.html
2. https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders
3. https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView

Comment: is it possible to use it in recyclerview

Comment: this is not working in my case i could'nt add this library into my project

Comment: and this is fast scroller completely irrelevant to this question am asking about section indexer

Answer (score -1):

Check this out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html
This seems like it could solve your problem. In order to get your data sorted alphabetically you can specify a sort order in the query itself.

Comment: i can sort it alphabetically but need to set alphabetical first letter as header

Comment: Read the description of the constructor - AlphabetIndexer (Cursor cursor, 
                int sortedColumnIndex, 
                CharSequence alphabet) The third parameter takes a charsequence where each character represents one section. Read the description to get a better idea.